# Slider Not Displaying Correctly in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, nivo-slider

I've added the Nivo Slider to a website and made some CSS modifications. When the site is viewed in IE9 however, there is a large black square covering the left-hand side.

http://genesisoak.com.au/

All of my CSS adjustments so far have been in vain, so I'm turning to you guys for help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add to your **section class "slide" (.slide)** this CSS property (in your stylesheet document)

```
right: 0;
```

This property will attach the section to the right of the page and will solve the problem.

That's all you need.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me. I tried adding the suggested line of CSS and it didn't seem to fix the problem. Any other ideas?